# How to change the background color of the iOS status bar for Safari Web Apps?

Tags: html, iphone, css, web-applications, safari

I'm trying to find a way to change the background color of the iOS status bar for a mobile web app that I'm currently working on. I've seen several solutions for native applications, but I need a solution that works for Safari and Chrome if possible.

The documentation I've been able to find shows that the following options are available:

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">`

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">`

`<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">`

Is there a way to edit the meta tag so that the background color would be "#ff8000"?

Is there another way other than editing the meta tag to change the background color of the status bar?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729700

Answer (score 14):

Just stumbled across this, my solution was to put this in head:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ff8000" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Try This:

On your index.html>head tag use this:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
```

You also need to set the:
    body { background-color: #yourcolor } 
in the styles.css

It worked for me last time I tried, but remember to fill up the manifest.webmanifest with this information as well